# formatting of the divs(responsive)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>Responsive</title>
    <style>
        .city {
            float: left;
            margin: 5px;
            padding: 15px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 300px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        .city2 {
            float: left;
            margin: 5px;
            padding: 15px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100px;
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body background="page-bg.jpg">

    <h1>W3Schools Demo</h1>
    <h2>Resize this responsive page!</h2>

    <div style="width:100%">
        <div style="width:21%;" >
            <div class="city2">
                <h2>London</h2>
                <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="width:21%;float:left;">
            <div class="city2">
                <h2>Paris</h2>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="width:21%;">
            <div class="city2">
                <h2>Tokyo</h2>

            </div>
        </div>


        <div style="width:21%;">
            <div class="city2">
                <h2>Istanbul</h2>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>





    <div style="width:100%">

        <div style="width:33.3%">
            <div class="city">
                <h2>London</h2>
                <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
                <p>It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div style="width:33.3%">
            <div class="city">
                <h2>Paris</h2>
                <p>Paris is the capital and most populous city of France.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div style="width:33.3%">
            <div class="city">
                <h2>Tokyo</h2>
                <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan, the center of the Greater Tokyo Area, and the most populous metropolitan area in the world.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Above is my code which has 4 divs in row 1 and 3 divs in row 2. I am trying to make the divs responsive. For that there is css mentioned as `city,city2` in the code. When the code is rendered the first four divs dont come in a straight line. Plus, when I resize the window, the arrangement is responsive but there is white space in front of those 4 divs. Plese help how I can make them responsive and occupy the screen in every dimension of the screen.

[image: Responsive when window resized]

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like this, may it will helps you.

```css
        .city {
            float: left;
            margin: 5px;
            padding: 15px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 300px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            box-sizing:border-box;
        }

        .city2 {
            float: left;
            margin: 5px;
            padding: 15px;
            width: 100%;
            min-height: 120px;
            border: 1px solid red;
            box-sizing:border-box;

        }
```

```html
    <h1>W3Schools Demo</h1>
    <h2>Resize this responsive page!</h2>

    <div >
        <div style="width:21%;float:left;margin-right: 10px;">
            <div class="city2">
                <h2>London</h2>
                <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="width:21%;float:left;margin-right: 10px;">
            <div class="city2">
                <h2>Paris</h2>
                <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="width:21%;float:left;margin-right: 10px;">
            <div class="city2">
                <h2>Tokyo</h2>
                <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>

            </div>
        </div>


        <div style="width:21%;float:left;margin-right: 10px;">
            <div class="city2">
                <h2>Istanbul</h2>
    <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>





    <div>

        <div style="width:32%;float:left;margin-right:8px">
            <div class="city">
                <h2>London</h2>
                <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
                <p>It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div style="width:32%;float:left;margin-right:8px">
            <div class="city">
                <h2>Paris</h2>
                <p>Paris is the capital and most populous city of France.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

  <div style="width:32%;float:left;">
            <div class="city">
                <h2>Tokyo</h2>
                <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan, the center of the Greater Tokyo Area, and the most populous metropolitan area in the world.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This helps me a little. Please see my edit(added new image).

Answer (score 1):

Simple improvement, hope that help you start and that you will improve this example :)

```css
*{
 box-sizing:border-box;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
body{
 background-image: url("page-bg.jpg");
 font-size:80%;
 max-width:1200px;
 margin:0 auto;
}
h1, h2{
 padding:5px;
}
.row1{
 width:100%;
}
.one{
 width:21%;
 min-width:300px;
 float:left;
 padding:5px;
 margin:0 auto;
}
.inside {
    float: left;
    padding:5px;
    width:100%;
    min-height:120px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.row2{
 width:100%;
 clear:both;
}
.two{
 width:33%;
 min-width:400px;
 float:left;
 padding:5px;
 margin:0 auto;
}
.city {
 float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>Responsive</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Demo</h1>
    <h2>Responsive page</h2>

    <div class="row1">
        <div class="one">
            <div class="inside">
                <h2>London</h2>
                <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="one">
            <div class="inside">
                <h2>Paris</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="one">
            <div class="inside">
                <h2>Tokyo</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="one">
            <div class="inside">
                <h2>Istanbul</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row2">
        <div class="two">
            <div class="city">
                <h2>London</h2>
                <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
                <p>It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="two">
            <div class="city">
                <h2>Paris</h2>
                <p>Paris is the capital and most populous city of France.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="two">
            <div class="city">
                <h2>Tokyo</h2>
                <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan, the center of the Greater Tokyo Area, and the most populous metropolitan area in the world.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, you need to change only one thing for `.one` class: delete `width:21%` and paste `width:100%`. The extra space is now occupied by divs.